# Give me back admin rights on Win7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I (current user) was a member of **Administrators** group. I changed my group to another one. Now, I can't change back to Administrators:

[image: Access denied when changing group to Administrators]

Also, this command (and several others) was denied:

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

[image: net command denied]

**How to become a member of Administrators group again?**

Comment: Did you make sure to run the net user command from an elevated CMD prompt?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Right click `cmd.exe` and "Run as admin" does the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-join the Administrators group through the Windows' built-in (but almost always hidden) Administrator account. The command you're trying to execute (`net user administrator /active:no`) actually **disables** the built-in Administrator account and I'm not sure why you would execute this... Because that would leave the computer with no accessible account that has Administrator rights, access is denied.

Log in using the Windows' built-in Administrator account (if not visible in the login screen, use this on an elevated command prompt: `net user administrator /active:yes`) and re-add your user to the Administrators group. You can then disable the built-in Administrator account using the command.

Comment: Unfortunately, `net user administrator /active:yes` also denied

Comment: And I don't now Administrator password :(

Comment: My system admin logged on as Administrator and added me to Administrators group. Problem solved. Thanks @BloodPhilia :)